# I need to do a lodash filter based on the key of a child element

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I am trying to use lodash to filter objects in a react app.

```
const filteredContacts = _(contacts)
        .map((contact, id) => ({_id: id, ...contact}))
        .filter(contact => !(this.state.filter && contact.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1 && contact.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter) == -1))
        .filter(c => {
            _(c.courses)
                .map((course, id) => ({_id: id, ...course}))
                .each(course => {
                    console.log(course._id)
                    return (course._id == this.state.courseId)
                })
        })
```

This is pulling from a firebase database, so there are nodes which are just a key, no value, that then have children.  In this case I have capitalized where those are below.

contacts > USERID > courses > COURSEID > coursedata

or

```
contacts: {
  -uf39uhef2: {
    name: blah,
    courses: {
      -dfh92ehfdsfhw: {
        coursename: name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that my second filter is all kinds of wrong - I just pasted the last iteration of a million tries.  this.state.courseId is the course ID I want to filter by - how can I accomplish this?

I want to return all users that have a course ID matching the one set in state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filter check if the contact has courses, and if `coureses[this.state.courseId]` is truthy:

```
const filteredContacts = _(contacts)
        .map((contact, id) => ({_id: id, ...contact}))
        .filter(({ courses }) => _.has(courses, this.state.courseId));
```

```js
const contacts = {
  '-uf39uhef2': {
    name: 'blah',
    courses: {
      '-dfh92ehfdsfhw': {
        coursename: 'name'
      }
    }
  },
  '-willBeFiltered': {
    name: 'willBeFiltered',
    courses: {
      '-willBeFiltered': {
        coursename: 'name'
      }
    }
  }
};

const courseId = '-dfh92ehfdsfhw'; // courseId = this.state.courseId

const filteredContacts = _(contacts)
        .map((contact, id) => ({_id: id, ...contact}))
        .filter(({ courses }) => _.has(courses, courseId));

console.log(filteredContacts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do this without lodash:

```
const filteredContacts = Object.keys(contacts)
    .map((id) => ({_id: id, ...contacts[id]}))
    .filter(({ courses }) => courses && courses[this.state.courseId]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this got it for me.  Any hope I could ask you to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824649/how-to-filter-in-lodash-when-there-is-an-unknown-key which is a very similar (but slightly different) question?

Answer (score 1):

just use **_.pickBy** to to get needed users

```
_.pickBy(contacts, (user) => {
    return _.chain(user)
        .get('courses')
        .keys()
        .includes(courseId)
        .value();
});
```

another way

```
_.pickBy(contacts, (user) => {
    return _.has(user, ['courses', courseId]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this - while I selected a different answer because it required less modification of the code patterns in the app I'm in, this got me interested and playing with pickBy.  I have a second issue I'm looking at, would you mind checking it out as well - it is very similar...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824649/how-to-filter-in-lodash-when-there-is-an-unknown-key